# Windows 8 Authenticated Proxy no login prompt

Tags: windows-8, proxy

I'm using a windows 8 machine plugged into a LAN and trying to use the network's proxy server. The proxy requires authentication but the machine is not a domain PC.
This approach worked fine in XP and Windows 7 as the first request that hit the proxy (e.g. through IE) triggered a login prompt so I can enter my network credentials.  After that it all works fine and I could access the internet from any program which made use of the IE proxy settings.
In Windows 8 though no login prompt appears and the machine eventually locks up (can't even do a control-alt-delete.
I've tried using CNTLM which works for a while then itself eventually freezes.
Programs which use their own proxy settings such as Dropbox and firefox work fine.

So the question is what are the differences between Windows 7 and Windows 8 relating to proxy settings? Something must be preventing the authentication prompt in win8 but not in Win7.  I've read that defaults relating to whether or not to use NTLM 1/2 or LM authentication but I don't  know if that's related to my issue

NB: This question is not related to metro apps :)

Cheers

Comment: There isn't a difference.  If your computer is freezing there is a serious problem with the integrity of your system files.

Comment: Thanks Ramhound. This happened pretty much straight after a clean win 8 install.  Am pretty sure there is some kind of differents as the default registry entries around NTML authentication aren't the same between win7 and win8 but I don't know enough about them

Comment: Did you actually verify the problem exists on a clean installation or not?  "pretty clean" isn't clean "pretty clean" means "I installed applications that could be the reason".